# Content-Type Preflight Handling with AWS API Gateway versus Own Rest Server

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, aws-api-gateway

What is special with API Gateway, it is not required to include Access-`Control-Allow-Headers` in the response header.

This is AWS API Gateway Response Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 152
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Tue, 11 Oct 2016 02:39:40 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
x-amzn-RequestId: f3838f6a-8f5b-11e6-b13a-XXXXXXX
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 XXXXXXXXXXX.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX==
```

This is My Own Rest Server Response Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 335
Date: Tue, 11 Oct 2016 02:34:31 GMT
```

The Problem with My Own Rest Server is that I need include Access-Control-Allow-Headers in the response otherwise I will encounter `Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

With AWS API Gateway, I am **not** encounter that error even the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is not in response header.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), Content-Type should be allowed by default.

"Apart from the headers set automatically by the user agent (e.g. Connection, User-Agent, etc.), the only headers which are allowed to be manually set are:

- Accept
- Accept-Language
- Content-Language
- Content-Type

The only allowed values for the Content-Type header are:

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- multipart/form-data
- text/plain"

Hope that helps, Ritisha.

Comment: It is not allowed by default in chrome, because I need to include in Access-Control-Allow-Headers